# How to ask and say how old you are?

Tags: translation

How would you say "I am 25 years old" in Italian and ask "How old are you?" in Italian?

Comment: Tia27, I have to kindly ask you again not to post questions that can be easily answered using Google, without clarifying what efforts you've made and why the answers from Google don't satisfy you. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Quanti anni hai? Ho venticinque anni.

This is a question even [Google Translate can answer](https://translate.google.com/#en/it/How%20old%20are%20you%3F%20I%20am%2025%20years%20old.). Bear in mind that numbers in Italian are always written in letters unless they are dates.

Comment: "Grazie mille" or, "molte grazie" or, "grazie infinite".